# Google lighthouse issue - generating a mobile report

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, pagespeed-insights

The issue I am currently having is when trying to generate a performance report with google lighthouse and/or page speed insights for mobile devices. on desktop emulation I am getting a score of 99 but through mobile emulation it is not even detecting an FCP event. when actually viewing the site on mobile however, it is very responsive and quick to load. I'm not really sure why this may be the case and am not aware of any potential solutions. The only suspicion i have is that the site is not 'optimized' for mobile, as it is the exact same site for desktop just with layout adjustments using JS and CSS. The following image is of the localhost report (https://i.stack.imgur.com/13XnB.png)

to clarify this happens both locally and when hosted.

Things I have tried include:

- lazy loading image assets with react-lazy
- removing all 3d assets from the site temporarily (react-three-fiber)
- trying other analytics tools such as webpagetest (this was able to successfully generate a report and indicate the performance on mobile was not bad)
- async load all Api integrations such as google analytics, google reCAPTCHA
- pre-connect to all 3rd party resource URIs

Comment: may be try hosting your site, and re-running report via https://pagespeed.web.dev/

Comment: yes so the same issue occurs when using both page speed insight (after hosting) and with lighthouse locally